# React, onClick only works after second click, Axios, Async/Await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, onclick, fetch

I must be missing something very straight forward.
I am trying to make an axios GET request and then setState in an async/await function, I have also tried `fetch().then()`. The console.log() returns `undefined` unless I click `getData()` twice or put it in a separate `onClick()` event.  I think the state is being set correctly but the `console.log()` doesn't perform as I expect it.  Is there a way to `console.log()` in the same function as the axios request?  As always, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SalesGraph = () => {
  const [retrievedData, setretrievedData] = useState();

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const salesData = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/sales");
      await setretrievedData(salesData);
      console.log(retrievedData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  const showState = () => {
    console.log(retrievedData);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getData}>Graph</button>
      <button onClick={showState}>showState</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SalesGraph;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setretrievedData` is the asynchronous method and you can't get the updated value of `retrievedData` immediately after `setretrievedData`.

You need to get it in the `useEffect` by adding a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(retrievedData);
}, [ retrievedData ]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that answers my question however when I go to replace the console.log() with the functions I plan to use to process the new state, wont I encounter problems when they load on the first render, before the state is set?

Comment: you can check if retrievedData is null or undefined to trigger the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

All setters for react `useState` are async so even if you await your `setretrievedData` it will go on to the next line even before it is done.

To run any code only after the `setter` is done you need to add a `useEffect` and pass the `state` to watch as the 2nd arg